# How can I use ie (7~10) in windows 10

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I am using the windows 10 system , but I need to use the windows internet explorer versions between ie7 to ie10 for company work. I have search the net for so long a time, including the microsoft blogs but no result. Any body here know how to fix this event?

Comment: You can [download free virtual machines from IE8 to Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate it using the developer tool embedded in IE by hitting F12 on the  browser. Go To Emulation tab and change both the Document Mode and the User Agent String.

This is the reference to msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate it online using any of the online emulators like https://www.browserling.com/ for example.